# Hard Disk Not Recognised by BIOS RAID

Tags: hard-drive, bios, raid

Had Windows 7 Ultimate x64 installed on SATA Seagate Barracuda HDD connected to Intel Z68 motherboard processed by Intel Core i5-2500K processor and powered by Corsair VS 550 in a desktop.

12 volts on motherboard got fried a few days after installing and running Android SDK & Emulator. Got it fixed. Windows started rebooting after displaying “starting Windows” logo in normal mode. But, would boot in Safe Mode and run without any glitches. Chkdsk would not run after restart. Formatted normally to get rid of any MBR virus and re-install OS, but after loading files, OS installation  would stop and PC would reboot (not the usual reboots that take place during OS installation).

Updated BIOS. No luck. Ran Seatools to do a full erase  to write zeroes but hdd wasn't detected although BIOS detected & recognised it. Surfed forums and came to know about SATA controllers. Hdd was in AHCI mode in BIOS and was recognised by display of model number.

Changed from AHCI to RAID. Seagate recognises hdd. Ran full erase.

Changed from RAID to AHCI. Ran Seatools to check. Hdd not detected, although detected & recognised by BIOS.

**Problem :** Changed to RAID again, Seatools recognises hdd but BIOS only detects hdd but doesn't **recognise it** *i.e., BIOS displays “Device Detected” but not the hdd model number while in  AHCI mode, model number of hdd is displayed.*

Is this okay? Shall I proceed with the installation of OS in RAID although I have only one hdd? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could comment, but score isn't high enough yet.

The reset issue sounds a lot more like a memory problem than a disk problem. Also, bad memory or a bad memory controller can cause disk issues similar to what you are having.

That part aside, you'll need the RAID drivers handy as you install the OS - you'll probably need to do the INSERT DRIVER DISK dance when Windows asks where do you want to install. The ACHI drivers built into Windows won't handle the chipset correctly in RAID mode.

Comment: What reset issue are you talking about?